# Create EventReceiver when new site collection is created in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need a way to execute code when a new Site Collection is created.  I've looked at creating a web-scoped FeatureReceiver that gets executed when a new Web is created.  Then stapling this feature to all the site definitions, however Visual Studio 2010 isn't letting me deploy the module that contains the FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation directive.  It complains that the feature can't be deployed farm level (because it contains a Module).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use an Event Receiver instead of a Feature Receiver.  There is only an event for determining if a site collection is deleting/deleted.  There is an event for Web Adding/Provisioned however.  If you are creating a site immediately after creating the site collection one of those 2 events could be used to simply check the count of webs in the collection (0 or 1 depending on which web event receiver you use).  This would essential run your code on the creation of the first site within the site collection and should accomplish what you are looking for.